# Tomcat goes to .m2 directory for the jsp, servlet, etc. jars and crashes

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, maven

I am having trouble getting Tomcat to run JSPs on my maven-enabled project (Eclipse 3.7 with latest m2 plugin on Tomcat 6, running as a server in Eclipse Java EE):

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspInit(index_jsp.java:22)
```

This error indicates that the Tomcat-supplied jars for JSP, servlet, etc. are clashing with project jars. It does appear that everything is set up properly, though:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
  <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.5</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
  <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.1</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

If I turn on class tracing on the VM, I see that upon startup the jsp jar from Tomcat's lib directory is being used for JspFactory:

```
[Loaded javax.servlet.jsp.JspFactory from file:/C:/tomcat-6.0.28/lib/jsp-api.jar]
```

When the server is up and I'm ready to hit the jsp page for the first time, however, I get a different result:

```
[Loaded javax.servlet.jsp.JspFactory from file:/C:/Users/alice/.m2/repository/javax/servlet/jsp/jsp-api/2.1/jsp-api-2.1.jar]
```

So, for some reason that is beyond me, the jsp jar from the m2 repo is being used by the web application, even though the scope in the pom.xml is set to provided. I've exhausted google searching. What **other** configuration issues might be causing this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Over the last several years, I've regularly seen all sorts of configuration-related issues with the Tomcat Eclipse plugin.

I'd suggest doing yourself a huge favor - dump the plugin. Run a standalone Tomcat.
It's not that hard to do.

It's also easy to configure Tomcat to point to the war file that Eclipse builds, so that you don't have to explicitly deploy it.

It's also really easy to set up debugging of a standalone Tomcat instance.

The upside is that you don't have to deal with vagaries of the plugin, and generally speaking, stuf just works. As far as I can tell, there is no downside.

Comment: "...point to the war file that Eclipse builds" - Eclipse doesn't build a WAR file unless to explicitly ask it to do so, neither does m2e, right? You'd have to configure Tomcat to load the artifacts from the target directory (assuming you use Maven)?

Comment: Yes, if using maven (or maven with eclipse) you would have to configure your tomcat context to point to the war file in the project's target directory.

Comment: +1 m2e will 'autodiscover' wtp integration, which makes it possible to add your project to your tomcat instance.